# How can I configure Docker for developing and deploying a custom theme?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, customization

I am getting started with Docker and I'm still new to professional WordPress development practices. I would like to set up a Docker development environment (on my Mac) so that I can do custom WordPress theme development.

Assuming you have done this before and are already using Docker, how did you set this up? What does your Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml look like? I'm sure this has been done before. I wouldn't be surprised if there's already one-line command that can set this up for you.

**Update:** I've narrow this topic down to the following question:

#### How can I configure Docker for developing and deploying a custom theme?

Comment: I just had to delete two link only answers. As your question has 8 upvotes, would you mind narrowing it down to one question that is solvable?

Comment: @kaiser "Professional WordPress development" is not very well documented, so many people (including myself) are trying to learn how to work with WordPress in a professional way to develop and deploy custom WordPress themes. Using Docker helps to create an environment that mirrors the production environment, but it's also new territory, so I'd like to know how people are incorporating Docker into their WordPress development workflow.

Comment: Andrew, please take a look at [this text](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to see what kind of questions we keep open on this site. As it stands, your question is very subjective, open ended and only attracts opinion based or link only answers. Please change that, else we will have to close the question. Thanks.

Comment: @kaiser Okay, I've made my best attempt at changing this to be a more focused question.

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to post a partial answer to start the discussion in the hope of getting some helpful comments to fill in the blanks or alternative answers...

## Step 1: Install and Set Up boot2docker

Docker only runs on Linux. So in order to use Docker on our Mac, we need to install `boot2docker`, which will run Docker in a Linux VM. You can install `boot2docker` using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install boot2docker
```

Once it has finished installing, set up and start boot2docker:

```
boot2docker init
boot2docker start
```

Next, we need to run a command to set up some environment variables so that docker-compose will know to find Docker inside our boot2docker VM.

```
eval "$(boot2docker shellinit)"
```

You may want to add the lines that export variables to your `~/.bash_profile` so that you don't have to run the command every time you open a new terminal window.

## Step 2: Install docker-compose

There is a Docker plugin called `docker-compose` (originally called `fig`) which makes it really easy to define the relationship between your Docker containers. You can also install it using Homebrew:

```
brew install docker-compose
```

## Step 3: Create docker-compose.yml

There's an [official WordPress Docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) in the Docker registry. It includes some information about manually starting up Docker with all of the command line flags necessary to make it all work. As far as I can tell, you can skip all of that because we will be using `docker-compose`. In the directory where you will be working on your WordPress theme, create a `docker-compose.yml` with the following contents:

```
wordpress:
  image: wordpress
  links:
    - db:mysql
  ports:
    - 8080:80
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-theme-name

db:
  image: mariadb
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

The `volumes` configuration links our theme files in our current directory to a new theme directory inside the Docker container.

## Step 4: Start the containers

Run `docker-compose up` and you will set up two Docker containers ("wordpress" and "db") running an installation of WordPress.

## Step 5: Open the site in the browser

Our `docker-compose.yml` configuration specified that we are forwarding port 80 to port 8080. Also, `boot2docker` runs its VM on a specific IP address. Thus, in order to figure out the URL, we need to use the `boot2docker ip` command:

```
open http://$(boot2docker ip):8080
```

## Questions

Now that I have the containers up and running, I have a few questions...

1. Is there an automated way of setting up the boot2docker environment variables, other than copy and paste the exports listed in `boot2docker shellinit`?
2. When I'm working on a Rails application, I like to use [Pow](http://pow.cx/) so that I can access the app using a named `.dev` domain instead of working with specific ports/IPs. How can I configure my system (or Pow) so that I can access the host using http://mysite.dev?
3. Are there any steps that I missed? Or are there any steps that should be added to the end?

Comment: For your second question. You can try out docker nginx proxy: https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution for this is using Composer in combination with Docker. Docker handles the environment, Composer handles the dependencies, which includes themes, plugins, and any other packages I might need.

Here's my own local Docker setup:

https://github.com/alexmacarthur/wp-skateboard

And here's a branch that uses Composer to download the _s theme and place it in my `themes` directory:

https://github.com/alexmacarthur/wp-skateboard/tree/starter-theme-underscores